# What is the difference between "retired out" and "retired not out" in cricket?

Tags: cricket, history, terminology, wicket

I have seen the terms on scoreboard like: "retired out" or "retired not out". What does it mean and what is the different between there?

**Reference:**

- Mohammad Hafeez was retired out in ICC Champions Trophy Warm-up
  Matches, 2013 vs [South Africa](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-champions-trophy-2013/engine/match/634964.html)
- Gordon Greenidge was retired not out in 5th Test vs [India](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/63339.html).

Also I have seen "retired out" only on practice matches. Is there any case of "retired out" in international matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the history of Test match cricket there are only two times a batsman was out by this term retired-out. Both of them are [Srilankan](http://www.cricketcountry.com/cricket-articles/The-first-man-to-get-into-Test-record-books-as-retired-out-and-how/17748) cricket players and both the instances were held in a same [match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/63947.html).

Generally, retired-outs are happened only in [warm-up matches](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-champions-trophy-2013/engine/match/634962.html) where the result is not as much important. So this dismissal term was not included in the [standard dismissal terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dismissal_%28cricket%29).

Retired not-outs are very common as you said, it may be due to any reason, since the batsman can re-enter at anytime.

Answer (score 5):

#### Retired not out

If a batsman retires during his innings because of injury, illness or any other unavoidable reasons, and doesn't resume his innings, he is considered as *retired not out*. He can resume his innings after the wicket is fallen or other batsmen is retired. Retired not out is considered as *not out*.

#### Retired out

If a batsman retires during his innings for any reason other than injury, illness or any unavoidable reasons, and doesn't resume his innings, he is considered as *retired out*. He can resume his innings only with the consent of the opposing captain. Retired out is considered as *out*.

Reference: [Law 2.9 (Batsman retiring)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/)